# Right way to capture push notifications when the application is open in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

This is the first time I am integrating notifications into my application. I am using **Firebase**. Setup was extremely simple and I am able to view the notification in the tray.

So, when the application is open, and if it receives a notification. I would like to display the notification in the activity itself.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at Gmail approach. If there is new mail in current thread, they show `SnackBar` with notification.

You need to determinate connected parts of your app. And if notification connected to part where current user is - show `SnackBar`, and if there is something completely different - show heads-up notification.

Guide how to do `Heads-Up` notifications [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Guide how to do `SnackBar` notifications [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

Comment: Yes, I had the same thing in mind. I was wondering how to I notify the activity that a notification has come in

Comment: To notify activity use something like LocalBroadcastManager. Better to use something like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Thanks - looking at LocalBroadcastManager and EventBus. Seems like just what I wanted

Comment: This is perfect! And EventBus was just perfect! Took me less than 2 minutes :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried Pushbots , its an infra- Structure for Notifications , it has more interesting Features than Firebase. Give it a shot.

[Pushbots link](https://pushbots.com/)

Comment: Thanks, shall take a look.